# ASP.NET Core MVC model binding to list returns empty list in POST method?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a problem getting data bind to work properly to a list in my view model class. I'm using this from ASP.NET Core 1.1.2.

These are my view model classes:

```
public class ParameterViewModel
{
    public int ParameterValue { get; set; }
}

public class ConfigurationViewModel
{
    public List<ParameterViewModel> Parameters;

    public ConfigurationViewModel()
    {
        this.Parameters = new List<ParameterViewModel>();
    }
}
```

I have also defined a corresponding view template for the ParameterViewModel class:

```
@model HomeAutomationWeb.ViewModels.ParameterViewModel
<div>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.ParameterValue)</div>
```

I have verified that the view template is working correctly.

This is the Get method in my controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Index()
{
    var vm = new ConfigurationViewModel();
    vm.Parameters.Add(new ParameterViewModel());
    vm.Parameters.Add(new ParameterViewModel());

    return View(vm);
}
```

and the view looks like this:

```
@model HomeAutomationWeb.ViewModels.ConfigurationViewModel

<form asp-controller="Test" asp-action="Index" method="post">
    @for (var i = 0; i < Model.Parameters.Count; i++)
    {
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Parameters[i]) // binding works only with items which are accessed by indexer
    }
    <input type="submit" value="Update" />
</form>
```

and finally this is the Post method in my controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Index(ConfigurationViewModel vm)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // Update
    }

    return View(vm);
}
```

The problem is that the vm.Parameters list contains zero elements in my Post method.

I have verified that data binding back to my model works fine for simple properties (like an int) of my ConfigurationViewModel class, but it does not work for the property using the List.

This is the HTML generated:

```
<form method="post" action="/Test">
<div>
    <input class="text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-required="The ParameterValue field is required." id="Parameters_0__ParameterValue" name="Parameters[0].ParameterValue" type="number" value="0" />
</div>

<div>
    <input class="text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-required="The ParameterValue field is required." id="Parameters_1__ParameterValue" name="Parameters[1].ParameterValue" type="number" value="0" />
</div>

    <input type="submit" value="Update" />
<input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="CfDJ8Gpzz17DaqNCiNs_dLveO7S-kCKBOQ3lruobvlEbk8GO9pqH_qZpj_yn8YoAUxJuHu2me9e2-i2HZ0hG4CfvALnEwyOTMWACPhqAv6KF2uWPjGx3M2gW6G6hGhPly0FovX31iuhzxAllPkoRzaDluEz8nZzOeDY7ojPKkdnj3RMuQ7hw2K861Rc0Pw7iL5_viQ" /></form>
```

What could be the problem with my code?

Comment: As a side note, you do not need the `for` loop - just `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Parameters)` will generate the correct html for each object in the collection assuming your template view is `/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/ParameterViewModel.cshtml`

Comment: Yes, changing the Parameters member variable to a property fixed the problem!